# Cmake/cpack: how to create a libc++ static library deb without headers?

Tags: cmake, deb, libc++, cpack

I have been trying to create a deb for LLVM libc++ 3.4 on a Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit box tonight. I would like to first create a deb that just consists of just `/usr/lib64/libc++.a` without any headers.  Yes, I know per [Debian library packaging guide](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/column/libpkg-guide/libpkg-guide.html), I should include the file in a `*-dev` package, But being new to `cmake` and `cpack`, I would like to get there incrementally.

So, I first changed the `libcxx-3.4/lib/CMakeLists.txt` and added an if check (see line 14 and 18)

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt
 1  if (NOT LIBCXX_INSTALL_SUPPORT_HEADERS)
 2    set(LIBCXX_SUPPORT_HEADER_PATTERN PATTERN "support" EXCLUDE)
 3  endif()
 4  
 5  file(COPY .
 6    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/c++/v1"
 7    FILES_MATCHING
 8    PATTERN "*"
 9    PATTERN "CMakeLists.txt" EXCLUDE
10    PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
11    ${LIBCXX_SUPPORT_HEADER_PATTERN}
12    )
13  
14  if (${LIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED} MATCHES "ON")
15    install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/c++/v1/"
16      DESTINATION include/c++/v1/
17      )
18  endif()
```

Then, at in the `build` subdirectory, I issued a

```
CC=clang CXX=clang++ cmake -j2 -G "Unix Makefiles" -DLIBCXX_CXX_ABI=libcxxabi -DLIBCXX_LIBCXXABI_INCLUDE_PATHS="../libcxxabi/include" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ../libcxx -DLIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED=OFF
```

The created `deb` still consists of all headers.  If I commented out lines 14 to 18, then no headers were included in the package.  I am puzzled by this.  A variable defined for the parent `CMakeLists.txt` should be picked up by a child `CMakeLists.txt`.  What did I miss? I would appreciate a hint or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the answer for my own question.  Being new to `cmake` and `cpack`, I initially focused on the wrong `CMakeLists.txt`.  The `install` command for headers in the `include/CMakeLists.txt` is not the only one. The main `CMakeLists.txt` file has a marcro in which there is also an `install` command.  That should be disabled too.  Specifically:

In the main `CMakeLists.txt`, one could do:

```
   129    message(STATUS "Inside of setup_abi_libs; LIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED: ${LIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED}")
   130    if (LIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED)
   131      install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/"
   132        DESTINATION include/c++/v1
   133        FILES_MATCHING
   134        PATTERN "*"
   135        )
   136    endif()
   137  endmacro()
```

Then, in the `include/CMakeLists.txt`, one could do:

```
13  
14  message(STATUS "Inside of include; LIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED: ${LIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED}")
15  
16  if (LIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED)
17    install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include/c++/v1/"
18      DESTINATION include/c++/v1/
19      )
20  endif()
```

This is the end result that I was trying to obtain but failed last night:

```
$ dpkg-deb -c libcxx_3.4-1_amd64.deb 
drwxrwxr-x root/root         0 2014-03-04 08:59 ./usr/
drwxrwxr-x root/root         0 2014-03-04 08:59 ./usr/lib64/
-rw-r--r-- root/root   1928770 2014-03-04 08:58 ./usr/lib64/libc++.a
```

No more headers.  Now I just need to figure out how to change the original `CMakeLists.txt` files to make a real dev package :)

Comment: Hi Peter, to accept my own answer, there is a two-day waiting period. I will. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [documenation for if](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aif):

`MATCHES` is for regular expressions, use `if (LIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED)` or `if (${LIBCXX_ENABLE_SHARED} STREQUAL "ON")` instead

Comment: Peter. Thanks for responding. IMHO the issue is not related to the if syntax.  I tried both of what you suggested, but all headers are still included by `cpack`.  I will do a simple test case and see if I can figure it out.